# Meaning of field notation $[E:F]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, notation

Just a short question about notation.

For context, $K$ is a field and $a^{1/p}$ is an element that is not supposed to be in $K$. I do understand that $K(a^{1/p})$ means $K$ adjoined $a^{1/p}$, but what is the meaning of

$$[K(a^{1/p}):K]=p$$

Comment: It is the dimension of $K(a^{1/p})$ as a $K$-vector space. This is in *every* abstract algebra book.

Answer (score 5):

Given any field extension $E\supseteq F$, $[E:F]$ denotes the dimension of $E$ as an $F$ vector space. It's called the "index of $E$ over $F$" or "degree of $E$ over $F$."

Comment: Isn't it called the "degree"?

Comment: @Crostul Both, I've seen. I'll add that in too.